# Can not extend directly enum

Tags: java, android, enums

Guys here is my code and im taking an error all the time like you can not directly extend enum.Here is the code:

```
 public static final enum  ClimaMode  {

    public static final /* enum */ ClimaMode AUTO = new ClimaMode("AUTO", 0);
    public static final /* enum */ ClimaMode COOL = new ClimaMode("COOL", 1);
    public static final /* enum */ ClimaMode DRY = new ClimaMode("DRY", 2);
    private static final /* synthetic */ ClimaMode[] ENUM$VALUES;
    public static final /* enum */ ClimaMode FAN = new ClimaMode("FAN", 3);
    public static final /* enum */ ClimaMode HEAT = new ClimaMode("HEAT", 4);

    static {
        ClimaMode[] arrclimaMode = new ClimaMode[]{AUTO, COOL, DRY, FAN, HEAT};
        ENUM$VALUES = arrclimaMode;
    }

    private ClimaMode(String string3, int n2) {
        super(string3, n2);
    }



    public static ClimaMode valueOf(String string2) {
        return (ClimaMode)((Object)Enum.valueOf(ClimaMode.class, string2));
    }

    public static ClimaMode[] values() {
        ClimaMode[] arrclimaMode = ENUM$VALUES;
        int n = arrclimaMode.length;
        ClimaMode[] arrclimaMode2 = new ClimaMode[n];
        System.arraycopy(arrclimaMode, 0, arrclimaMode2, 0, n);
        return arrclimaMode2;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this ? Thanks...

Comment: Go and look at any enum example code. Instances are declared by `AUTO(...), COOL(...),` etc.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. It's just syntax confusion.